# Why can I not import data-tier application without access to all other databses?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to backup and restore a database located in Azure SQL database via Azure blob storage. To do this I have ran `Export Data-Tier Application...` on the selected database and successfully stored it in a blob container as a BACPAC file. Now I am trying to do the reverse and `Import Data-Tier Application...` to check the backup process functions correctly, however I receive the following error:

> 'The server principal "username" is not able to access database
>   "Database A" under the current security context'

The database it is referencing is the first listed database in the server I am trying to create a new database in which I don't have permissions for, and each time I give myself permission to access the first it just moves down the list to the next one and blocks me again. I don't understand why I need permissions for database A, B, C... to create a new database which is a copy of D, especially when I have the `db_manager` role so shouldn't have an issue with database creation.

Does this error indicate I am doing something wrong with the backup import, or is this a known issue and I need to have permissions for all databases in a server where I wish to import a backup to?

Answer (score 0):

Please update [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) (SSMS) to the latest version and try to export/import with the latest SSMS.

You can achieve the same using Azure portal. Open the appropriate database server page and then, on the toolbar, select Import database.

[image]

Select the storage account and the container for the BACPAC file and then select the BACPAC file from which to import. In addition, specify the new database size (usually the same as origin) and provide the destination SQL Server credentials.

[image]

You can also try with PowerShell.

```
$importRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport 
   -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" `
   -ServerName "<your_server>" `
   -DatabaseName "<your_database>" `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "<database_size_in_bytes>" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" -StorageAccountName "<your_storage_account").Value[0] `
   -StorageUri "https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/importsample/sample.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "P6" `
   -AdministratorLogin "<your_server_admin_account_user_id>" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your_server_admin_account_password>" -AsPlainText -Force)
```